# Create custom keyboard within app not external

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

How am I able to create a keyboard that is already enabled in the app, or is it just buttons put next to each other to make it seem like a keyboard. Like the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mkep.png

Answer (score 0):

you can use to the `UIButton` element or `UIView` with `TouchBegan`. But don't keyboard extension because different controller.

Comment: How am I able to make it look the same on both iPhone and iPad?

Comment: yes you do with Autolayout and Size classes. use to Adaptive Layout... Good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial and second tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ETCustomKeyboard](https://github.com/Djecksan/ETCustomKeyboard) which is mostly like same as you need.

And the output of that is show into below image:

[image]

You can modify this as per your need.

And [HERE](https://github.com/zxyah/CustomKeyboard) is one more same like that.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Create the keyboard as an ordinary UIView, and make it the `inputView` for your text field.  There is more information in Apple's [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) page.